# ngRoute is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngroute

I am creating an Angular App.The file structure is as follows:

```
index.html
login.html
js/index.js
```

`index.html` content is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

        <title>Hello World</title>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="single-page-app">
    <div ng-view>   </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`js/index.js` content is

```
var app1=angular.module('single-page-app',['ngRoute']);
app1.config(function($routeProvider){
      $routeProvider
          .when('/',{
                templateUrl: '../login.html'
          }).otherwise()
});
```

and `login.html` content is

```
<form class="form-horizontal"  style="position:absolute;top:30%;left:20%">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-offset-2">
    <label for="userName" class="col-xs-3 control-label">UserName</label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-offset-1" id="userName" placeholder="UserName">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-offset-2">
    <label for="password" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
      <input type="password" class="form-control col-xs-offset-1" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class=" col-xs-12">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-xs-offset-4">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I open `index.html` on server using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, there is no content of `login.html` file in `index.html`. Can anyone tell me why ng-route is not working in the above case??

Comment: Not much troubleshooting information provided. Use browser dev tools console to check for errors and see what is happening with the actual ajax request for template

Answer (score 2):

First: `templateUrl` should be relative to the app root. I don't think `../login.html` is valid.

If the templates are located within the website root directory, try this

```
var app1=angular.module('single-page-app',['ngRoute']);
app1.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
      .when('/',{
            templateUrl: '/login.html' // the edited line
      }).otherwise()
});
```

Second: As of angular 1.3, a `<base>` tag should be added to the `<head>` section.

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: I've never used `app` tag, where is this documented that it is *required*?

Comment: `<base>` is not required if you are not using html5mode

Comment: @charlietfl — Unless your base is not `/`.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you have to have some kind of value inside of `.otherwise()` or just remove it. Then it will work